# How to get multi level array value in PHP decoded from JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am facing a problem while printing an array in PHP. I am getting data from facebook API for user events and getting the result in JSON.

I just want to get each location (City,Country). Is there any method to get them easily?

I have tried:

```
$myjson=json_decode($_POST['Data'],true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myjson["data"]);
echo "<pre>";
echo count($myjson["data"]);
echo "<pre>";
for($i =0; $i<count($myjson["data"]); $i++){
    print($myjson["data"][$i]["name"]);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

When I decode the data and use `print_r`:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myjson["data"]);
```

I get the following result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => this is test
            [name] => test event Web Developer
            [place] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Lahore
                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [city] => Lahore
                            [country] => Pakistan
                            [latitude] => 31.5497
                            [longitude] => 74.3436
                        )

                    [id] => 108104849224069
                )

            [start_time] => 2015-10-21T19:00:00+0500
            [id] => 1503962379902466
            [rsvp_status] => attending
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => (Full description omitted for brevity)
            [name] => Peaceful Pakistan Online Competition!
            [place] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Punjab Information Technology Board (PITB)
                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [city] => Lahore
                            [country] => Pakistan
                            [latitude] => 31.5497
                            [longitude] => 74.3436
                            [zip] => 54600
                        )

                    [id] => 340860042630070
                )

            [start_time] => 2015-08-10T00:00:00+0500
            [id] => 907352572664461
            [rsvp_status] => attending
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [description] => (Full description omitted for brevity)
            [end_time] => 2015-06-17T19:30:00+0500
            [name] => Open House 2015
            [place] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 6th Floor, Arfa Software Technology Park, 346-B, Ferozepur Road, Lahore, Pakistan-54000
                )

            [start_time] => 2015-06-17T16:30:00+0500
            [id] => 1619010958352625
            [rsvp_status] => attending
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [description] => A Two Day Workshop on Game Design and Development on Unity 3d
            [end_time] => 2015-04-26T16:00:00+0500
            [name] => Game Design And Development Workshop
            [place] => Array
                (
                    [name] => House #75, Sarfaraz Rafique Road, Opposite P.A.F Sports Stadium, Lahore Cantt
                )

            [start_time] => 2015-04-26T10:00:00+0500
            [id] => 1651929135026796
            [rsvp_status] => attending
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [description] => (Full description omitted for brevity)
            [name] => Live Chat with Experts: How Does Pakistan's Load Shedding Affect You?
            [place] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Islamabad, Pakistan
                )

            [start_time] => 2015-03-26T11:00:00-0400
            [id] => 347677685418059
            [rsvp_status] => attending
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [description] => (Full description omitted for brevity)
            [name] => 6th September – Defense Day of Pakistan
            [place] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Virtual Event
                )

            [start_time] => 2013-09-06
            [id] => 434438063339987
            [rsvp_status] => attending
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects, essentially. Since you're force decoding the JSON into an array you have an array of arrays.

Getting the city/country from each object in your example above is pretty simple.

```
foreach($myjson['data'] as $arr) {
    echo $arr['place']['location']['city'], ', ', $arr['place']['location']['country'], "\n";
}
```

The keys mapping to `place => location` provide an array with the `city` and `country` keys you're looking for. So `$myjson['data'][$i][place']['location']['city']` would give you the city and `$myjson['data'][$i][place']['location']['country']` would give you the country, but you can iterate over `$myjson['data']` with `foreach` more conveniently than using a `for` loop such as in your example above.

The first element would give you `Lahore, Pakistan`, for example.

Comment: I did something like this
`for($i =0; $i<count($myjson["data"]); $i++){
print($myjson["data"][$i]["name"]);
if(isset($myjson["data"][$i]["place"]["location"]["city"])){
echo "<br />".$myjson["data"][$i]["place"]["location"]["city"];
}`

Comment: Then please update your question with the **actual** code that you used and tell us what the result was and what you expected it to be that it wasn't. You seem to have left that code out completely from your question. Also, please use [`var_export`](http://php.net/var-export) and not `print_r` when providing the sample data from your array. Otherwise it's hard to know if the bug is in your code or in the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($myjson["data"] as $data){
  echo $data['place']['location']['city'];
  echo $data['place']['location']['country'];
}
```

Comment: do i can use nested for loop to get these values

Comment: You could do this, but in your case it is not that efficient, I'd say

Comment: this shows Notice:  Undefined index: location in
If location value is not returned from facebook

Comment: it can be that some array elements don't have the 'location' index, as I see for example the 3rd one (A Two Day Workshop on Game Design and Development on Unity 3d). You need to check this using an if statement

Comment: nice and thanks 

in php we use isset() function to check array elements have key or not 
Now i am using
` if(isset($myjson["data"][$i]["place"]["location"]["city"])){
echo "<br />".$myjson["data"][$i]["place"]["location"]["city"];
}`

it works fine for me Thanks

Comment: isset() can do the trick, you could also use array_key_exists() as an alternative and more appropriate method

Comment: array_key_exists() i think you this is good method to check Thanks